# Communication between Object of ObservableCollection and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Let's say I have this in my `ViewModel` class. *(Notice the `OnSubmit` function)*

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase{
    
    private string? _SomeName;
    public string? SomeName{
        get => _SomeName;
        set {
            Validate(nameof(SomeName)); //Validate data on changes
            SetProperty(ref _SomeName, value);
        }
    }
    
    //Call this function to Validate the input data
    private void Validate(string propertyName){
        ClearError(propertyName);
        switch(propertyName){
            case nameof(SomeName):
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_SomeName)) 
                    AddError(nameof(SomeName), "Name cannot be empty.");
            break;  
            ...
            //other validation for propeties here if present
        }
    }
    
    private ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>? _Transactions;
    public ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>? Transactions{
        get => _CodeItemDisbursement;
        set {
            SetProperty(ref _Transactions, value); 
        }
    }
    
    //ICommand Add new item to ObservableCollection
    private readonly ButtonCommand _AddItem;
    public ICommand AddItem => _AddItem;
    private void OnAddItem(object commandParamater){
        _Transactions.Add(new TransactionItem(){
            ... //add the data here...
        });
    }
    
    //ICommand Form Submission
    private readonly ButtonCommand _Submit;
    public ICommand Submit => _Submit;
    private void OnSubmit(object commandParamater){ //Validate all data before processing it.
        //Validate all input is correct before we proceed.
        Validate(nameof(SomeName));

        // How do I call here, the `Validate()` function 
        // of each item in my `ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>`
        // and check if `HasErrors` property has some value?
    
        if(HasErrors) return; //There are errors, do not proceed.
        
        //If no errors, then do process the data here...
    }
    
    //ViewModel Constructor
    public MyViewModel() {
        _Submit = new ButtonCommand(OnSubmit);
        _AddItem = new ButtonCommand(OnAddItem);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an `ObservableCollection` with an object of `TransactionItem`, and here is the `TransactionItem` class.

```
public class TransactionItem : ViewModelBase{
  
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string? Description { get; set; }
  public string? OtherDetails { get; set; }
  
  private string? _TransactionName; 
  public string? TransactionName { 
    get => _TransactionName; 
    set {
        Validate(nameof(TransactionName)); //Validate data on changes
        SetProperty(ref _TransactionName, value); 
    }
  }
 
  private decimal _Amount;
  public decimal Amount { 
    get => _Amount; 
    set {
        Validate(nameof(Amount)); //Validate data on changes
        SetProperty(ref _Amount, value); 
    }
  }
  
  //Call this function to Validate the input data
  private void Validate(string propertyName){
    ClearError(propertyName);
    switch(propertyName){
        case nameof(TransactionName):
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_TransactionName)) 
                AddError(nameof(TransactionName), "Name of transaction cannot be empty.");
        break;
        case nameof(Amount):
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Amount.ToString()) || _Amount < 1) 
                AddError(nameof(Amount), "Please input a valid amount");
        break;  
    }
  }

}
```

I also have a class of `ViewModelBase` that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo{
    
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null){
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(member, value)) return false;
        
        member = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyDataErrorInfo | Error Handling
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _propertyErrors = new();
       
    public bool HasErrors => _propertyErrors.Any();
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs>? ErrorsChanged;

    public void ClearError(string? propertyName){
        if (propertyName!=null && _propertyErrors.Remove(propertyName)) OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public void AddError(string propertyName, string errorMessage){
        if (!_propertyErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) {
            _propertyErrors.Add(propertyName, errorMessage);
        }else{ 
            _propertyErrors[propertyName] = errorMessage;
        }
        if (propertyName != null) OnErrorsChanged(propertyName); 
    }
    
    private void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName){
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string? propertyName){
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            yield break;
        if (_propertyErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out string? existingError))
            yield return existingError;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

What happened here is that, when the `OnSubmit` function is triggered from the `ViewModel` class, I want to call the `Validate()` function to check if every required property has the correct input. Then if the `HasErrors` property from my `ViewModelBase` has a value, then do not proceed to process the data.

The problem is in my `ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>`. I also want to call the `Validate()` function in the object `TransactionItem` to validate the `TransactionName`, and `Amount` of each item and not proceed if `HasErrors` has a value. But I'm lost and I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Could you just have OnSubmit() run a for loop on IEnumerable<TransactionItem> and call Validate(), you would have to make it a public function, and have Validate() return the status of HasErrors when it completes.  Then in the loop you can cancel the submission if errors are found?

Comment: @ErikKinstler could you elaborate?

Comment: See the answer posted by @Polar

Answer (score 1):

You could make a public function in your `TransactionItem` that triggers the `Validate()` and returns the value of `HasErrors`, then run a loop in your `OnSubmit()` and call that function in every item of your `ObservableCollection<TransactionItem>`. If any of it returns true, then do not proceed.

For example, create a public function in your `TransactionItem`

```
public bool ContainsError(){
    Validate(nameof(TransactionName)); //Validate data on changes
    Validate(nameof(Amount)); //Validate data on changes
    return HasErrors;
  }
```

Then in your `ViewModel` class, in `OnSubmit()` function do this

```
private void OnSubmit(object commandParamater){ 

    Validate(nameof(SomeName)); //First, validate your SomeName or other propeties.
    
    bool ContainsError = false;
    foreach(TransactionItem item in _Transactions){
        ContainsError = item.ContainsError();
    }
    
    if(HasErrors || ContainsError) return; //There are errors, do not proceed.
    
    //If no errors, then do process the data here...
}
```

That should do.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was talking about in my comment +1

Comment: Ohh, I see! I'm overthinking too much. Anyway, is there any other approach? What if I have multiple items in my observablecollection? It will block the UI, right?

Comment: @Bolomeo An `event` would do, but I would not recommend it since you will need to handle other things like unsubscribing on it. This approach is the easiest, and if your problem is blocking UI then you can use `Async/Await`.

Comment: Shouldn't the line below `foreach` loop be `ContainsError |= item.ContainsError();`? Also `.Any()` could be used instead.